# How to set something to always be the last display?

Tags: java

I have a "club" and there will be members of said club.

I have this for my first class:

```
private String first;
private String last;
private static int members = 0;

public tuna(String firstName, String lastName){
    first = firstN;
    last = lastN;
    members++;
    System.out.printf("%s %s\nMembers: %d", first, last, members);
   }
}
```

and I have

```
class thing {
   public static void main(String[] args){

    tuna member1  = new tuna("Megan", "Fox");
    tuna member2 = new tuna("Mila", "Kunis");
    tuna member3 = new tuna("Melanie","Iglesias");
   }
}
```

and when I run it, I get this:

```
Megan Fox
Members: 1Mila Kunis
Members: 2Melanie Iglesias
Members: 3
```

But I want "Members: 3" to be the only "Members" text displayed, and I want it at the end of the program. so I want it to display as:

```
Megan Fox
Mila Kunis
Melanie Iglesias 

Members: 3
```

Comment: Please don't set **all** your text to bold in your posts. That defeats the whole purpose of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust `tuna` to have a `getMemberCount()` method when you've completed adding members to your class.

Example:

We change the `printf` statement to `System.out.printf("%s %s\n", first, last);`.

We add an accessor in `tuna` called `getMemberCount()`, which returns a `static int`.  This is a choice made because the **count of the objects** is **independent from the object's data itself**.

```
public static int getMemberCount() {
    return members;
}
```

Lastly, you call `getMemberCount()` as so:

```
System.out.println("Members:" + tuna.getMemberCount()); // Gets the member count.
```

You can call static methods just by using the class name (analogous to `Integer.parseInt()`), which means you won't need to create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
System.out.printf("%s %s\nMembers: %d", first, last, members);
```

Add these method to your class:

```
public int getMembers() { // accessor for members field
    return members;
}
protected void finalize() { // decrement member count when one is destroyed
    members--;
}
```

Add this to your main method after your `member3` declaration:

```
System.out.println("Members: " + member3.getMembers());
```

Comment: A static integer is a perfectly good way to count members.
Also, this answer does not result in the desired output.

Comment: I would've recommended extracting the static `members` field out of the tuna class, although the code functions the same.

Comment: I suggest you read this!: http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-Objects.shtml#instance-count

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize he was counting instances. In that case he also needs a destructor.

Comment: `members` is out of the scope of `thing`, by the way, and should be called `tuna.members`, anyway, as this *is* a static variable reference.